# Domain Driven Design Model for handling images

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, entity-framework

I have to create model which will handle various types of images in my app.

**INTRO**

Plan is to have one `Image` type which will be universal and then extended with specific types of image, for example `UserUploadedImage` which will have reference to User who uploaded image, privacy level etc.

Currently I have `Image` type implemented. The idea behind implementation was to create entity which will be behaviour rich, follow SOLID and other OO principles (such as [TellDontAsk](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html), etc.).

Also, I wanted to create entity as POCO class which would be independent of any frameworks and persistence logic.

**General structure**

- Entity - Entity class, inherited by all other entities

  - Has generic Id and implements `IEquitable`
- Image - Entity
- ImageMemento - implementation of [memento pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern)

  - I got inspiration for this in book [PPPDDD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1118714709) `ImageMemento` is basically  used both as support for undo mechanism and mapping between "real" entity class and its database persisted version (`PeristedImage`)
- PeristedImage - handles persistence of `Image` entity

  - I am using Entity Framework ORM to handle persistence, `PersistedImage` is object which will be actually stored in database
- Project also implements UoW and Repository patterns and I will present code for ImageRepository

**CODE**

One more note about Image. It has to support "Image Variants" - for example if someone uploads 500 x 500 *.png* image, some of the variants would be: 100 x1 00, 200 x 200 *.jpg* etc. (different sizes, and types of same image).
Original image has to hold reference to all variants.

**Image**

```
/// <summary>
///     Purpose of image is name suggest is handling of images
///     <para>
///         Image variants are also supported
///         Image variant is essentially same image but different width, height and url
///     </para>
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="Guid" />
/// <autogeneratedoc />
public class Image : Entity<Guid>
{
    private static readonly HashSet<string> SupportedImageExtensions = new HashSet<string>
    {
        "jpg",
        "jpeg",
        "png"
    };

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Image" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">Image name.</param>
    /// <param name="extension">Image extension.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Image width.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Image height.</param>
    /// <param name="url">Image URL.</param>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public Image(string name, string extension, int width, int height, string url)
    {
        //clans up the data
        name = name.Trim();
        extension = extension.Trim();
        url = url.Trim();

        //Forces the invariants
        //Invariants are attributes or business rules that should never change
        ForceInvariants(name, extension, width, height, url);

        Id = Guid.NewGuid();

        Name = name;
        Extension = extension.ToLowerInvariant();
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Url = url.ToLowerInvariant();
        CreatedOn = DateTime.UtcNow;


        Variants = new List<Image>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Image" /> class from its memento.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memento">The image memento.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">memento - Image memento cannot be null</exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private Image(ImageMemento memento)
    {
        if (memento == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(memento), "Image memento cannot be null");
        //just in case
        ForceInvariants(memento.Name, memento.Extension, memento.Width, memento.Height, memento.Url);

        if (memento.Id == Guid.Empty)
            throw new ArgumentException("Id cannot be empty", nameof(memento.Id));

        Id = memento.Id;
        Name = memento.Name;
        Extension = memento.Extension;
        Width = memento.Width;
        Height = memento.Height;
        Url = memento.Url;

        CreatedOn = memento.CreatedOn;

        Variants = memento.Variants;
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the Image.
    ///     <para>
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The name.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the extension of the image.
    ///     <para>
    ///         Some of supported extensions are: jpg, png and jpeg
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The extension.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private string Extension { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the width of the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The width.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private int Width { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the height if the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The height.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private int Height { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the URL where image is actually located.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The URL.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private string Url { get; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When was image firstly created
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Creation date
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private DateTime CreatedOn { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Variants are list of images which are actually same as this image, but with different width, height & URLs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The variants.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private ICollection<Image> Variants { get; }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates image memento.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Image memento</returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public ImageMemento GetMemento()
    {
        return new ImageMemento(Id, Name, Extension, Width, Height, Url, CreatedOn, Variants);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Reverts image to its previous state from the memento
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memento">The memento.</param>
    /// <returns>Image reverted from memento</returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public static Image CreateFrom(ImageMemento memento)
    {
        return new Image(memento);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Creates the variant of the image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image variant.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">image - Image variant cannot be null</exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public void AddVariant(Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image), "Image variant cannot be null");
        }

        Variants.Add(image);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the number of variants.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The number of variants</returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public int GetNumberOfVariants()
    {
        return Variants.Count;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Makes sure that business requirements are respected
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    ///     More info: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Class_invariant
    /// </remarks>
    /// <param name="name">Image name</param>
    /// <param name="extension">Image extension.</param>
    /// <param name="width">Image width.</param>
    /// <param name="height">Image height.</param>
    /// <param name="url">Image URL.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">
    ///     name - Image name cannot be empty
    ///     or
    ///     extension - Image extension cannot be empty
    ///     or
    ///     url - Image url cannot be empty
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">
    ///     Image name cannot be longer than 50 chars - name
    ///     or
    ///     Image extension cannot be longer than 5 chars - extension
    ///     or
    ///     Image extension not supported
    ///     or
    ///     Provided url is not valid - url
    /// </exception>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
    ///     width - Image width cannot be less than 1px
    ///     or
    ///     width - Width is too large it cannot be over 4000px
    ///     or
    ///     height - Image height cannot be less than 1px
    ///     or
    ///     width - Height is too large it cannot be over 4096px
    /// </exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    private void ForceInvariants(string name, string extension, int width, int height, string url)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name), "Image name cannot be empty");

        if (name.Length > 50)
            throw new ArgumentException("Image name cannot be longer than 50 chars", nameof(name));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(extension), "Image extension cannot be empty");

        if (extension.Length > 5)
            throw new ArgumentException("Image extension cannot be longer than 5 chars", nameof(extension));

        if (!SupportedImageExtensions.Contains(extension))
            throw new ArgumentException("Image extension not supported");

        if (width <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(width), "Image width cannot be less than 1px");

        //note this is 4k (4096 x 2160) resolution
        if (width > 4096)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(width), "Width is too large it cannot be over 4000px");

        if (height <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(height), "Image height cannot be less than 1px");

        //note this is even more than 4k (4096 x 2160) resolution
        if (height > 4096)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(width), "Height is too large it cannot be over 4096px");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(url))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(url), "Image url cannot be empty");

        //we have to check whether provided url is actually valid url
        //according to SO post this is the best way to do it
        //more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7581824/1284262
        var urlIsValid = Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.Absolute, out var uriResult)
                         && (uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp || uriResult.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps);
        if (!urlIsValid)
            throw new ArgumentException("Provided url is not valid", nameof(url));
    }
}
```

**ImageMemento**

```
/// <summary>
///     This is Memento for the Image class
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
///     <para>
///         Memento pattern was suggested in book PPP of DDD
///     </para>
///     <para>
///         For more info about memento got o this link:
///         http://www.dofactory.com/net/memento-design-pattern
///     </para>
/// </remarks>
/// <autogeneratedoc />
public class ImageMemento
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImageMemento" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public ImageMemento()
    {
        Variants = new List<Image>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImageMemento" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="name">The name.</param>
    /// <param name="extension">The extension.</param>
    /// <param name="width">The width.</param>
    /// <param name="height">The height.</param>
    /// <param name="url">The URL.</param>
    /// <param name="variants">The variants.</param>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public ImageMemento(Guid id, string name, string extension, int width, int height, string url, DateTime createdOn,
        ICollection<Image> variants)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Extension = extension;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Url = url;
        CreatedOn = createdOn;
        Variants = variants;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The identifier.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public Guid Id { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the Image.
    ///     <para>
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The name.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Name { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the extension of the image.
    ///     <para>
    ///         Supported extensions are: jpg, png and jpeg
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The extension.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Extension { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the width of the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The width.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public int Width { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the height if the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The height.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public int Height { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the URL where image is actually located.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The URL.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Url { get; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Variants are list of images which are actually same as this image, but with different width, height & URLs
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The variants.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public ICollection<Image> Variants { get; }
    /// <summary>
    /// When was image firstly created
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Creation date
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get;  }

}
```

**PersistedImage**

```
/// <summary>
/// Purpose of this class is to map actual <see cref="Image"/> entity class to this model which will be persisted to database
/// </summary>
/// <autogeneratedoc />
public class PersistedImage 
{
    public PersistedImage()
    {

    }

    public PersistedImage(Guid id, string name, string extension, int width, int height, string url, DateTime createdOn)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Extension = extension;
        Width = width;
        Height = height;
        Url = url;
        CreatedOn = createdOn;
        ParentImage = null;
    }

    public PersistedImage(Guid id, string name, string extension, int width, int height, string url,DateTime createdOn,
        PersistedImage parent) : this(id, name, extension, width, height, url, createdOn)
    {
        ParentImageId = parent.Id;
        ParentImage = parent;
    }



    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The identifier.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the name of the Image.
    ///     <para>
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The name.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the extension of the image.
    ///     <para>
    ///         Supported extensions are: jpg, png and jpeg
    ///     </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The extension.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the width of the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The width.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public int Width { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the height if the image in pixels.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The height.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public int Height { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets or sets the URL where image is actually located.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    ///     The URL.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public string Url { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// When was image firstly created
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// Creation date
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; } 

    public Guid? ParentImageId { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the parent image.
    /// <para>
    /// Parent image is image from which this image was created as variant
    /// If null, this is original image
    /// </para>
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The parent image.
    /// </value>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public PersistedImage ParentImage { get; set; }


    /// <summary>
    ///     Maps the specified memento to persisted image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memento">The memento.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public static PersistedImage Map(ImageMemento memento)
    {
        return new PersistedImage(memento.Id, memento.Name, memento.Extension, memento.Width, memento.Height,
            memento.Url, memento.CreatedOn);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Maps the specified memento to persisted image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="memento">The memento.</param>
    /// <param name="parentImage">The parent image.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public static PersistedImage Map(ImageMemento memento, PersistedImage parentImage)
    {
        return new PersistedImage(memento.Id, memento.Name, memento.Extension, memento.Width, memento.Height,
            memento.Url, memento.CreatedOn, parentImage);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Maps the specified image to image memento.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image.</param>
    /// <param name="images">The images.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public static ImageMemento Map(PersistedImage image, ICollection<Image> images)
    {
        return new ImageMemento(image.Id, image.Name, image.Extension, image.Width, image.Height, image.Url,
            image.CreatedOn, images);
    }
}
```

**ImageRepository**

```
/// <inheritdoc />
/// <summary>
///     Repository for dealing with various images
/// </summary>
/// <seealso cref="!:Master.Domain.DataAccessLayer.Repository.Generic.MasterRepository{Master.Domain.Model.Image.PersistedImage, System.Guid}" />
/// <seealso cref="T:Master.Domain.DataAccessLayer.Repository.Image.IImageRepository" />
/// <autogeneratedoc />
public class ImageRepository : MasterRepository<PersistedImage, Guid>, IImageRepository
{
    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="T:Master.Domain.DataAccessLayer.Repository.Image.ImageRepository" />
    ///     class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="unitOfWork">The unit of work.</param>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public ImageRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
    {
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds the image to repository.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image to add.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">image - Image cannot be null</exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public void Add(Model.Image.Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image), @"Image cannot be null");
        var persistedImage = PersistedImage.Map(image.GetMemento());
        DbSet.Add(persistedImage);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds the image to repository with all the variants
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image.</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">image - Image cannot be null</exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public void AddWithVariants(Model.Image.Image image)
    {
        if (image == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image), @"Image cannot be null");

        //just in case check if there are actually any variants, if not just image as it is
        if (image.GetNumberOfVariants() < 1)
            Add(image);

        var imgMemento = image.GetMemento();
        var imageToPersist = PersistedImage.Map(imgMemento);

        DbSet.Add(imageToPersist);

        foreach (var variant in imgMemento.Variants)
        {
            var variantMemento = variant.GetMemento();
            DbSet.Add(PersistedImage.Map(variantMemento, imageToPersist));
        }
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Adds the variant of the image.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image">The image to which variant is added.</param>
    /// <param name="imageVariant">Image variant</param>
    /// <exception cref="T:System.ArgumentNullException">image - Image cannot be null</exception>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public void AddVariant(Model.Image.Image image, Model.Image.Image imageVariant)
    {
        if (image == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image), @"Image cannot be null");

        //firstly we add variant to the list of variants in image object
        image.AddVariant(imageVariant);
        //then we get persistence model
        var parentImagePersisted = PersistedImage.Map(image.GetMemento());
        //then we get persistence model of the variant
        var imageVariantToPersist = PersistedImage.Map(imageVariant.GetMemento(), parentImagePersisted);
        //finally we actually persist it
        DbSet.Add(imageVariantToPersist);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets image the by id without variants
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     The image
    /// </returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public async Task<Model.Image.Image> GetByIdWithoutVariantsAsync(Guid id)
    {
        //gets image from db
        //but it is in its persistence model
        var persistedImage = await GetAsnyc(id);

        //so we have to map it to actual image
        return persistedImage == null
            ? null
            : Model.Image.Image.CreateFrom(PersistedImage.Map(persistedImage, new List<Model.Image.Image>()));
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the image with all variants included.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id">The identifier.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     Image with all the variants
    /// </returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public async Task<Model.Image.Image> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
    {
        var rootPersistedImage = await DbSet.FirstOrDefaultAsync(r => r.Id == id);

        if (rootPersistedImage == null)
            return null;

        var variants = (await DbSet.Where(r => r.ParentImageId == rootPersistedImage.Id).ToListAsync())
            .Select(r => Model.Image.Image.CreateFrom(PersistedImage.Map(r, new List<Model.Image.Image>()))).ToList();
        var rootImageMemento = PersistedImage.Map(rootPersistedImage, variants);

        return Model.Image.Image.CreateFrom(rootImageMemento);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc />
    /// <summary>
    ///     Finds the invariants which satisfy given condition.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image"></param>
    /// <param name="condition">The condition.</param>
    /// <returns>List of image variants which satisfy condition</returns>
    /// <autogeneratedoc />
    public async Task<List<Model.Image.Image>> FindVariantsAsync(Model.Image.Image image,
        Expression<Func<PersistedImage, bool>> condition)
    {
        var persistedVariants = await DbSet.Where(r => r.ParentImageId == image.Id).Where(condition).ToListAsync();
        return persistedVariants.Select(r => Model.Image.Image.CreateFrom(PersistedImage.Map(r, new List<Model.Image.Image>())))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the scope of `DbSet` and what s its life span?

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your comment!  DbSet is exposed trough Unit of Work. It goes like this: UoW is injected in Repos and Services. In UoW DbContextFactory (which is  singleton factory) is injected. UoW in constructor calls DbContextFactory which creates new DbContext instance. Both DbContext and UoW *live* during one request. This is ensured by Ninject: `kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>().InRequestScope();`

Comment: @GertArnold I have also posted my UoW & Repo implementations here on code review before, you can find more details [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175468/c-entity-framework-repository-pattern-unit-of-work-pattern)

Comment: Hi
I like your code but there are a couple of things that I dont get.
Could you post an example of how to perform "undo"?
Do you really need to separate between image and persisted image or I just getting confuse because of the names?

Comment: Hey, I am not actually performing undo, I haven't implemented this functionality yet, as I don't find it necessary at the moment. I decided to completely  separate Image and persisted image mainly because of Entity Framework, I wanted to have my entities "clean" from ORM stuff. For example Image has list of variants,  but PersistedImage has pointer to ParentImage - that is how I decided to design "Varaint" handling with EF. Up to my knowledge I believe this separation wouldn't be necessary with NHibernate because it seems to be much better ORM, but I haven't had any experience with it.